# Como dividir los elementos de 2 listas

Tags: python, lista

Necesito dividir estas 2 listas(por medio de sus elementos) y agregar el resultado de la division de sus elementos en una nueva lista uwu

```
    import random
lista=[]
def isPrime(valor):
    for i in range(2,valor):
        if (valor % i ==0):
            return 0
            break
    return valor


#vamos a añadir a la lista solo los primos
tempo=0
while len(lista)<20:
    tempo=isPrime(random.randint(1, 100))
    if tempo !=0:
     lista.append(tempo)

#mostrar la lista
print(lista)
#####################################################################


lista2=[]
def isPrime(valor):
    for i in range(2,valor):
        if (valor % i ==0):
            return 0
            break
    return valor


#vamos a añadir a la lista solo los primos
tempo=0
while len(lista2)<20:
    tempo=isPrime(random.randint(1, 100))
    if tempo !=0:
     lista2.append(tempo)

print(lista2)
```

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""

[image: unu]

como se ve en la imagen necesito dividir esos valores y el resultado de la division de los valores agregarlos a una nueva lista

Comment: Quieres, por ejemplo, dividir `11/19` y el resultado agregarlo a `lista3`?? Si es así puedes hacer `lista3 = [a/b for a,b in zip(lista1, lista2)]`

Comment: La solución de @Christian es la más sencilla y elegante. ¿Por qué no la pasas a respuestas?

Answer (score 1):

#### Usando "for" recorriendo elementos

Para dividir 2 listas elemento por elemento podes recorrer cada elemento de las listas a través de sus índices. para eso podes utilizar un for

```py
lista1 =[10,15]
lista2=[5,10]
lista3=[]
for i in range(0,len(lista1)):
    lista3.append(lista1[i]//lista2[i])

print(lista3)
```

#### Forma reducida formando tuplas ("zip y for")

Una forma más corta (estílo python) es usando la función `zip` que forma tuplas:

```py
lista1 =[10,15]
lista2=[5,10]
lista3 =[a//b for a,b in zip(lista1, lista2)]
print(lista3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar `numpy` ya que soporta operaciones entre listas y matrices

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = np.array([2,4,6])
list2 = np.array([2,2,2])
print(list1/list2)
```

Resultado:

```
array([1., 2., 3.])
```

Aplicándolo a tu código

```
import random
import numpy as np
lista= []
def isPrime(valor):
    for i in range(2,valor):
        if (valor % i ==0):
            return 0
            break
    return valor


#vamos a añadir a la lista solo los primos
tempo=0
while len(lista)<20:
    tempo=isPrime(random.randint(1, 100))
    if tempo !=0:
     lista.append(tempo)

#mostrar la lista
npLista1 = np.array(lista)
print(npLista1)

#####################################################################

lista2=[]
def isPrime(valor):
    for i in range(2,valor):
        if (valor % i ==0):
            return 0
            break
    return valor


#vamos a añadir a la lista solo los primos
tempo=0
while len(lista2)<20:
    tempo=isPrime(random.randint(1, 100))
    if tempo !=0:
     lista2.append(tempo)
    
npLista2 = np.array(lista2)

print(npLista2)

npLista3 = npLista1 / npLista2

print(npLista3)
```